# On iOS, how can I force AVRoutePickerView to allow route switching between speaker and the handset?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, airplay

Right now, when the user presses the `AVRoutePickerView`, they get a choice of `iPhone` and other AirPlay targets. And picking `iPhone` uses the speakerphone to play back audio:

[image: Current Situation]

I'd like there to be an option to switch between `iPhone` and `Speaker`, where `iPhone` routes the audio to the internal handset speaker, and `Speaker` routes audio to the speakerphone. That's how other apps on the phone seem to work (Phone, Google Voice, and some others):

[image: The way it should be]

Comment: Just a guess, try adding/removing `.defaultToSpeaker` option in `AVAudioSession`

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that. I tried multiple AVAudioSession modes, categories, and options. Maybe there's a specific combination that's required for this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, but I'm pretty pissed off at Apple for basically not having any documentation about how things are supposed to work!

In essence, you have to `overrideOutputAudioPort` on `AVAudioSession` after calling `setCategory`, but before calling `setActive`. It doesn't matter which route you want to use for the override (`.speaker` or `.none`) -- either way, it'll now allow you to chose either the Speaker or iPhone in `AVRoutePickerView`. Here's an example:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord)
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Comment: Note that presense of the speaker option in AVRoutePickerView depends on the mode you've set. For example, if you use AVAudioSession.Mode.videoChat, speaker won't show up but is automatically used unless you lift receiver to your ear.  Per Apple's header about some of the modes: "Reduces the number of allowable audio routes to be only those that are appropriate for video chat applications."   BTW, if you option-click in Xcode on each mode in Apple's AVAudioSession header, you'll get more details than in Apple's docs on the web or even better than the comments in the header itself.